# Always show last row data only

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a table inside a Razor view. This foreach loop runs 3 times as I have 3 items. However in this table shows only last row items every time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  @foreach (var item in Model.NewsModel)
  {
    @:gTable = "<tr class=\"xl1\">";
    @:gTable += "<td>";
    @:gTable += "<input value=" + @item.NewsNo + " class=\"form-control\" />";
    @:gable += "</td>";
    @:gTable += "</tr>"
  }
  document.getElementById('newsTbl').innerHTML = gTable;
});
```

Comment: It's because your first line of the loop redefines `@:gTable`. You need to define it outside the loop and use `+=` within it

Answer (score 1):

Every time you run the loop, it initialises gTable, and then you add to it.

After all the loops complete you're setting the innerHTML of the element to the table.

Your variable is being reset on every iteration of the loop. So you might wanna initialize it outside of the loop to be an empty string and always `+=` to it after that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
@:gTable = "<tr class=\"xl1\">";
```

On each iteration the `@:gTable` lost all of its data and re-initializes it. So declare it out side of loop and concatenate new value on each iteration using `+=`.